# About changing the context where a javascript function runs

Tags: javascript, scope, call

I solved a problem I had, by realizing that if you define a javascript function in a certain context, you cannot call it to run in a different context. Now, I have been exploring ways to accomplish that.

My goal is: I have three windows: The first one is the main window, where my function was created. The second is a newly opened window using `window.open`. This second window has a button to open the third and last window, making that after opening, that third one should run the same function that was defined in the first window.

I have tried to reference this third window in the main function like this:

(assuming that the name of my `window.open` variable is `w` )

```
var w;
function main() {
    console.log(w);
    ...rest of the code....
}
```

so I was hoping that it would give a hint to the main function, of the existence of W, the window that I would open later on.

Then, from the second window I would create a button and make an `onclick`:

```
w.main;
```

which wouldn't work...

Is there a different method (or a way to change this one) to make a function aware of the existence of a different context where it was created, so when the moment arrives in the future, is able to run inside of it?

I am reading now about adapting `call()` to my purpose. Does it make sense, or you would suggest a different way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to define a function in window 1 and then call that method from window 3 with the context of window 3 (meaning using window 3's variables instead of window 1's)? Maybe if you could clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a function already defined in window 1. Then window 1 opens a new window (window 2) and from that window 2, I open a third window (window 3) which will run the code defined in window 1 :-) Think, like a search engine: the window 1 has the text box and the search button, the window 2 shows the results list, and the window 3 opens the result site, using a function that was defined in window 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming window 1 opens window 2 and window 2 opens window 3
and you are trying to call the main method in window 1 from window 3

```
window.opener.opener.main();
```

to set w in window 1 to the window 3 reference when opening it in window 2:

```
window.opener.w = window.open();
```

Ok i tested this out.
A dialog opens displaying "test" in window 1 after window 3 opens

window1.html:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var child = window.open("window2.html", "window2");

        function test() {
            alert("test");
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

window2.html:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var child = window.open("window3.html", "window3");
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

window3.html:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.opener.opener.test();
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm... this thing with `window.opener.opener.main()` gives me a: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'window.opener.opener')

Comment: and this was executed in the context of the third window? I've never tried chaining opener in a row like that before, so maybe that is the problem? Although I feel like that should work.

Comment: Would be easier for me to understand the problem if you posted the code at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, it was executed in the context of third window... I will look into jsfiddle, but the code is around 1000 lines, I don't think it's a very good idea... well, thank you anyways for your tip! I will keep looking into it, maybe I do something else wrong.

Comment: the example i just displayed could be further edited so the method in window1 displays the dialog in the window that calls the method (window3 in this case)

Comment: You are right! This is just the thing I need. I will keep trying to adapt it to my program, but your codes proves that it's the exact same thing I am missing.